# How to deliver form parts based on user's permission in ASP.NET

Tags: rendering, webforms, privileges

I am developing an application in ASP.NET and I have a page that depening on user's role displays different parts. If the user is an Admin s/he sees for instance a page part where to input a new user and role that a normal user cannot see. Let's think about this page as a portal.

I already wrapped all the different sections in  with Id and I can control their visibility. However this is not the optimal solution concerning security since the user or a malicious robot can still fill and access the parts that are not visible in the browser.

With MVC it is easy since I just create several partial views and render them upon users' credentials but how do you do it in standard Web Forms? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASP.NET LoginView control. The control has an AnnonymousTemplate which you can use to specify which content should be shown to Annonymous users, and a LoggedInTemplate which you would use to specify the content shown to logged in users. But is also has RoleGroups which can be used to specify content that can be shown to users in different roles.

The article in this link will walk you through the use of this control.

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2010/07/28/role-based-authorization-using-loginview-control.aspx